# Tortoise ORM. Add additional field to PydanticListModel class generated by pydantic_queryset_creator function

Tags: fastapi, pydantic, tortoise-orm

Can you tell me how, when using `tortoise.contrib.pydantic.pydantic_queryset_creator`, to add an additional field that is generated when querying the database?

Here is the query:

```
categories = await EquipmentCategory \
    .filter(equipment__organization__inn=organization_inn) \
    .annotate(equipment_count=functions.Count('equipment')) \
    .order_by('-equipment_count') \
    .limit(3) \
    .all()
```

The `pydantic_queryset_creator(EquipmentCategory)` class does not contain the `equipment_count` field, and it is needed during serialization.

I tried to inherit and redefine the field:

```
class EquipmentCategoryListPydantic(pydantic_queryset_creator(EquipmentCategory)):
    equipment_count: int
```

But it leads to the exception:

```
ValueError: __root__ cannot be mixed with other fields
```

I really don't want to rewrite everything from scratch (using `pydantic.BaseModel`) and repeat the whole code twice!

I hope for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! (But is it a good solution?).

I inherited the abstract ORM class `EquipmentCategoryWithEquipmentCount` from the original ORM class `EquipmentCategory` and added the `equipment_count` field to it. Later on in `pydantic_queryset_creator` I just used this class:

```
class EquipmentCategory(models.Model):
    name = fields.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = fields.DatetimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class PydanticMeta:
        exclude = ["created_at", "equipment"]


class EquipmentCategoryWithEquipmentCount(EquipmentCategory):
    equipment_count = fields.IntField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

EquipmentCategoryListSchema = pydantic_queryset_creator(EquipmentCategoryWithEquipmentCount)
```

Comment: is this solution still working well? I cannot using pydantic_model_creator with this abstract class, it reports " default_connection for the model <class 'app.models.domain.xxxx'> cannot be None"